# Some objects not rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to render a group of cylinders with volume materials however some of them are not showing up. What's causing this?

[image]

Here is the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bp0fha9gyalf0g/renderhelp.blend?dl=0

Thanks for helping!

Comment: There is a issue with the materiel Change the materiel ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your objects are too thin.  To fix this, you could scale your object up along the Z axis, or increase the *Density Scale*, or change the material type to *Surface*.  I would recommend changing the material type.